# Function return type is wrong after if else expressions

Tags: scala

I have the following function which returns a list of 8 elements or list:

```
def orderCost(orderItems: List[Double]) = {

if (orderItems.length <= 8) orderItems else orderItems.grouped(8).toList

}
```

So my question is that why my function is returning List[Any] instead of List[Double] or List[List[Double]]. Is there a bug 2.11.8 which i'm using.

orderItems can be one of the below:

```
orderItems: List[Double] = List(4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99)
```

or

```
 orderItems: List[Double] = List(4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99)
```

> I want to a list of eight elements if order item length is 8 or create a multiple list from order item, where each sub list contains 8 elements max

Thanks

Comment: You have stated that if `orderItems.length > 8` then you want a `List[List[Double]]` right? In this case, no matter what the type of the List, you will get a `List[List[Double]]` back using something like `orderItems.grouped(8).toList` - what is the problem with returning a `List[List[Double]]`? Probably best to make this explicit with a return type as others have said and a comment as to why an argument that is `<= 8` will return a `List[List[Double]]` containing only 1 sub list. The caller can then decide how they wish to work with it.

Comment: Is this efficient because i new to scala

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? Performant? As you have worded your question, you have actually asked to get back a `List[List[Double]]` which you have a solution for. Are you asking, "Is there a better data structure I could return?" To answer that you need to provide more info. ie. how big could `orderItems` be and what are you planning to do with the returned list?

Comment: The return type depends on the orderItems length because a list can only hold 8 elements max for my use case. yes performance in terms of memory. The order items can grow in the future but at the moment i don't know the maximum.

Comment: Because of what you want `orderCost` to do, you have to return some collection[collection] right? How do you intend to work with the returned collection?  That should help point you in the right direction in terms of which data structure to return.

Comment: @Nio, I want add the elements up using the sum function. so the dataStructure list[Any] does not allow me to do that but if i get list[Double] or list[list[Double]] works fine using the map(._sum)

Comment: What about just combining your operations then `def orderTotals(orderItems: List[Double]): List[Double] = orderItems.grouped(8).toList.map(order => order.sum)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to check length, You can do directly like this

```
def orderCost(orderItems: List[Double]) = {

     orderItems.grouped(8).toList

  }
```

Sample Input 1:

```
val orderItems: List[Double] = List(4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99)
```

Sample Output 1:

```
List(List(4.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99), List(8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99), List(8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99))
```

Sample Input 2:

```
val orderItems1: List[Double] = List(1,2,3,4,5.8)
```

Sample Output 2:

```
List(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.8))
```

Comment: Hi Manoj, I want to a list of eight elements if order item length is 8 or create a multiple list from order item, where each sub list contains 8 elements max

Comment: @mike Then you need not to check length you can right just - orderItems.grouped(8).toList code in your function.

Comment: That works but it returns List[List[Double]] instead of list[Double]. Is this efficient.

Comment: Yes, If you want to return both the formats the return type will be List[Any]

Comment: how to convert from List[Any] to List[Double] or List [ List[ Double ] ]. I have tried as.insteadof but i could not use the sum function

Comment: Then you have to use scala pattern match like - val sum: Seq[Double] =ans.map{ ele=> ele match {case x:Double=>x; case list:List[Double]=>list.sum }}

Comment: @ Manoj I will go with your answer and Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just change the return of the function. `grouped` with take care of all cases.

```
def orderCost(orderItems: List[Double]): List[List[Double]] = 
   orderItems.grouped(8).toList
```

## Scala REPL

```
scala> val l = (1 to 10)
l: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 10

scala> l.grouped(8).toList
res0: List[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = List(Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Vector(9, 10))

scala> val l = (1 to 4)
l: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 4

scala> l.grouped(8).toList
res1: List[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = List(Vector(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

So, function looks like

```
scala> def orderCost(orderItems: List[Double]): List[List[Double]] = orderItems.grouped(8).toList
orderCost: (orderItems: List[Double])List[List[Double]]

scala> orderCost(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
res2: List[List[Double]] = List(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0))

scala> orderCost((1 to 20).toList.map(_.toDouble))
res4: List[List[Double]] = List(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0), List(9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0), List(17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0))
```

Comment: Hi Pamu, I want to a list of eight elements if order item length is 8 or create a multiple list from order item, where each sub list contains 8 elements max

Comment: Thanks Pamu but  but it returns List[List[Double]] instead of list[Double]. Is this efficient?

Comment: @mike yes, please check my updated answer for more information

Comment: the return type of function will not be known upfront. But it can be a list[Double] or list[List[Double]] again this is determined by the length of order item. Each list can have 8 elements max.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the only type that is compatible with both `List[Double]` and `List[List[Double]]` is `List[Any]`, so that is the result type of the function. There are no union types (until 3.0) so you can't return `List[Double] | List[List[Double]]`.

You can unpick the current return value with a `match` statement (but beware type erasure). Or you could return `Either[List[Double], List[List[Double]]` like this:

```
def orderCost(orderItems: List[Double]) = {
  if (orderItems.length <= 8) Left(orderItems) else Right(orderItems.grouped(8).toList)
}

orderCost(myItems) match {
  case Left(ld) => // Handle List[Double]
  case Right(lld) => // Handle List[List[Double]]
}
```